# Android: Lock the Background image but rotate foreground views

Tags: android, locking, orientation, background-image

I have a Landscape background image in place. How do I lock it into position, but allow forground views to be rotated, e.g. a Dialog.

At the moment, either I lock the orientation so the dialog doesn't rotate, or I don't lock it and the background becomes tiny as I rotate the screen and it fills the narrow width of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to allow the rotation and just display a different background (the original background rotated 90 degrees)

You can catch the rotation in onConfigurationChanged, once you've added android:configChanges="orientation" to your activity in the manifest

Comment: You can have the two versions of the background stored in drawable-port and drawable-land resource folders. Then the system will automatically load the correct version for you. That avoids having to add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to the manifest, which creates a lot of work for you because you then have to handle all aspects of orientation changes.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but, if I have different background images for lots of different activities and also have different backgrounds for different screen resolutions and then for different rotations, then thats hell of a lot of memory, most of which a single user will never benefit from. I think I may try to lock the orientation and then try to use a 'tween' animation to rotate the dialog as the orientation change is captured. Your comments please!